# Can you use ActivationSpec values to initialize MDB?

Tags: java, ejb, jca

I have a JCA resource adapter that sends messages to a message-driven bean (MDB).  I would like to be able to use the ActivationSpec properties to initialize the MDB instance.  Is it possible to get the ActivationSpec while executing ejbCreate() in the MDB?

Answer (score 0):

The activation config is intended for the RA, not the MDB.  There is no spec-defined way for an MDB to access its activation config.